# Why am i picking up 2 blockchains for my BTC address

Tags: bitcoin-cash, blockchain-fork, coinbase.com, coinbase-transaction, bitcoin-wallet-app

So this is my address
38UPP6po1NJvNQoTavvTBzbRi1bKcyR7tZ

And i am picking up 2 blockchains ,one for BTC and BCH ? I did a transfer a week ago and i am not sure why i cant see the funds in my coinbase account ?

Please help

Comment: Did you send Bitcoin Cash to your BTC account?

Answer (score 1):

> **I am picking up 2 blockchains, one for BTC and BCH?**

There are a vast amount of numbers that are valid Bitcoin-addresses (BTC). Most of them have never been used and never will be.

Many of these same numbers are also valid Bitcoin-cash addresses (BCH) because of the way Bitcoin Cash was created.

So your address is a valid address in at least four different cryptocurrencies.

> **I did a transfer a week ago**

That address has only ever been used in Bitcoin-Cash (BCH). It was used [once last week](https://blockchair.com/bitcoin-cash/address/38UPP6po1NJvNQoTavvTBzbRi1bKcyR7tZ).

That address has never been used in Bitcoin (BTC) and never had any amount of Bitcoin associated with it.

> **I am not sure why I can't see the funds in my Coinbase account?**

If the above doesn't help, you should probably contact Coinbase and ask them for assistance.